# How to replace number with another set of number with vertical line

Tags: java, string

How to replace number with another set of number with vertical line

Example , I got a group of number as below

```
"118|142|4000000|99|8|1372055573|0"
"119|12|600|9|8|1866573|0"
"120|126|85600|9|8|1866573|0"
```

and I want to replace all number from the end to `"x|y|2900|99|20|99999999|0"`
both `x`, `y` still the same number.

Then after run a code , the summarize is

```
"118|142|2900|99|20|99999999|0"
"119|12|2900|99|20|99999999|0"
"120|126|2900|99|20|99999999|0"
```

Comment: Find 2nd index of | and then take all up to that index from the original string and concatenate it with intended replacement string 2900|etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex could suit your needs:

```
"((?:[^|]+\|){2})[^"]+"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

*Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0CECWhhUsdE8cKsS)*

Replace by:

```
"$12900|99|20|99999999|0"
```

*Demo on [RegExr](http://regexr.com?36m5j)*

Java use:

```java
String in = "\"118|142|4000000|99|8|1372055573|0\",\"119|12|600|9|8|1866573|0\",\"120|126|85600|9|‌​8|1866573|0\"";
String out = in.replaceAll("\"((?:[^|]+\\|){2})[^\"]+\"", "\"$12900|99|20|99999999|0\"");
```

Comment: what I must change if data in the same line.

"118|142|4000000|99|8|1372055573|0","119|12|600|9|8|1866573|0","120|126|85600|9|8|1866573|0"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trivial solution

```
    String str[] = new String[]{"118|142|4000000|99|8|1372055573|0", "119|12|600|9|8|1866573|0"};
    String[] oldTokens = str[0].split("[|]");
    String[] newTokens = str[1].split("[|]");
    StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < newTokens.length ; i ++) {
        if(i < 2)
            strBuff.append(oldTokens[i]);
        else strBuff.append(newTokens[i]);
        if(i < newTokens.length) {
            strBuff.append("|");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(strBuff.toString());
```

Comment: This `|` should be escaped, [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) takes a *regex* and not a String.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: If you look carefully its not "|" its a pattern [|]. It does show the result.

Comment: That's what happen when I comment early in the morning.. ;)

Comment: No problems have a cup of coffee ;)

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons Lang has a StringUtils class which has a join function which will join arrays together to make a String.

Here is an example with one line

```
public class Test {
    public static void main() {
        String s = "118|142|4000000|99|8|1372055573|0";

        String[] parts = s.split("|");

        parts[2] = "2900";
        parts[3] = "99";
        parts[4] = "20";
        parts[5] = "99999999";
        parts[6] = "0";

        String newString = StringUtils.join(parts, "|");    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial solution. But this code is reusable. You can use it as you want.

```
String original  = "118|142|4000000|99|8|1372055573|0";
String toFind    = "4000000|99|8|1372055573|0";
String toReplace = "2900|99|20|99999999|0";
int ocurrence    = 1;
String replaced  = replaceNthOcurrence(original, toFind, toReplace,ocurrence);
System.out.println(replaced);
```

The function code for `replaceNthOcurrence` :

```
public static String replaceNthOcurrence(String str, String toFind, String toReplace, int ocurrence) {
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(toFind));
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(str);
int i = 0;
while (m.find()) {
if (++i == ocurrence) { sb.replace(m.start(), m.end(), toReplace); break; }
}
return sb.toString();
}
```